# Stream close error when using "using" syntax

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stream

I'll leave my original question below. My question is why does the following lines produce an exception

(you can see it run at http://www.ideone.com/rfQLE)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace CSQuick
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ff = new MemoryStream())
            using (var f = new StreamWriter(ff))
            {
                f.WriteLine("Hi");
                using (TextReader ts = new StreamReader(ff))
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception from ideone website (possibly using mono? I am running MSVS 2010 C# which causes an exception)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.CheckIfClosedThrowDisposed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.FlushBytes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

---

Why am i getting a exception with the msg "Cannot access a closed Stream." ? What i like to do is use a streamwriter to write text and store the final results in temp. The below should do that but i dont understand how or why my stream is closed?

```
using (var ff = new MemoryStream())
using (var f = new StreamWriter(ff))
{
    foreach (var t in blah)
    {
        blahblah(t, f);
    }
    ff.Flush()
    using (TextReader ts = new StreamReader(ff))
    {
        temp = ts.ReadToEnd();
        do_a_check(fn, temp);
    }
}//Cannot access a closed Stream.
```

Comment: What line gives the error? the `using` calls dispose which calls `close`

Comment: If you getting error where comment is, so it should be, because when using statement ends it disposes object.

Comment: @Oskar: The last line. the `}`. @Ren: Yes so i close/dispose both objects. But... what is this error about. Does one obj close the other? And even if thats so shouldnt the dispose or GC still be fine... i still dont get it

Comment: Could you show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Can you check the stack trace? if the bracket indeed does throw the error, the stack trace should show the dispose method calling

Comment: Calling flush on a memorystream doesn't do anything because the buffer and the memory it represents are the same. This probably doesn't solve your problem but saves you a line of code.

Comment: @Jon: Well... This simple code http://www.ideone.com/9w8HA doesnt repo the error BUT if you use code analyses on it, it does give an CA2202 warning (disposing twice). Which... is insane...

Comment: @Jon: GOT IT! repo here. http://www.ideone.com/rfQLE I'll modify my question

Comment: @Jon: So it turns out my original paste shows all that is needed. Now that we have the answer, do you think this is a flaw in the libraries? specifically StreamReader/TextReader closing the stream that is passed in? or should it have done that?

Comment: @acidzombie24: What exactly do you mean by your "original paste"? The code originally in the question wouldn't compile... I think it's reasonable for StreamReader/TextReader to close the stream by default, but it would be nice to have a flag to disable that behaviour. Then again, if you run into this as a problem, you already have a separate issue that you've got unflushed data that you won't have read. (You also need to rewind the memory stream before reading...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that when you dispose the TextReader, the resources within it is disposed as well (the MemoryStream). So when the StreamWriter is disposed, it flushes, thus writing to the disposed MemoryStream.

Your small repro code could be changed to flush:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ff = new MemoryStream())
        using (var f = new StreamWriter(ff))
        {
            f.WriteLine("Hi");
            f.Flush();
            using (TextReader ts = new StreamReader(ff))
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Or you can set `AutoFlush` which will cause the stream to be flushed each write, then this exception won't be present if you do not put a write line after disposing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var ff = new MemoryStream())
    using (var f = new StreamWriter(ff))
    {
        f.AutoFlush = true;
        f.WriteLine("Hi");
        using (TextReader ts = new StreamReader(ff))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! a note tho. The first example it STILL causes an exception. However flushing f solves it.

Comment: @acidzombie24 You are correct. Can't believe I missed that, I thought I ran that code. You can also set to `AutoFlush`

Answer (score 5):

You didn't provide much information but I assume that the error is because when the StreamWriter using clause is done and StreamWriter is closed then also the underlying stream is closed as well. In this situation when You'll try to access the stream after the using statement You'll get the error "Cannot access a closed Stream"

```
using (var ff = new MemoryStream())
{
using (var f = new StreamWriter(ff))
{
//Some Code
}
//Stream ff is closed, because the StreamWriter has been closed while exiting the inner using statement
}
```

Comment: How do i fix it? do i NOT use the using keyword?... that kind of seems strange and wrong. BTW i adjusted my Q with a mini repo

Answer (score 0):

You should show the Stack trace which would be more useful.

As of now i think the problem would be `StreamReader` in the using block which on dispose is closing both the reader and the underlying stream

Answer (score -2):

In you're code this

```
using (var ff = new MemoryStream())
```

should auto dispose the MemoryStream, add some { } to expand the scope. Or remove the using code and simply add a try catch finally around the code.

Comment: you are wrong. `using` works like `for`: its scope is one operation unless there are {}. In the above case, the operation is the 2nd `using`, so It's OK

Comment: The scope is the same as the line below that using statement

Comment: But not everyone(even experience .net developers) know that and it has to be explained. So it might just be 'unwise' to do so. Rewriting the code to use try catch should pinpoint the exact reason for the code to fail.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't answer the question, don't post an answer. Also, in your answer you sounded like you were saying that was the reason for the exception